# module java.base does not read module java.desktop

Tags: java, jmockit, java-9, java-platform-module-system

When I run this test (using jmockit and TestNG, not sure if that's relevant):

```
public class Test {
  @Test public void test(@Mocked ProcessBuilder pb) throws IOException {
    new Expectations() {{ pb.start(); result = null; }};
    assertNull(m());
  }

  public static Process m() throws IOException {
    return new ProcessBuilder("").start();
  }
}
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class java.lang.ProcessBuilder (in module java.base) cannot access class javax.print.PrintException (in module java.desktop) because module java.base does not read module java.desktop

at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java)
....
```

I am using build 177.

I can rerun the test using `--add-reads java.base=java.desktop` argument and it works fine but I don't really understand what is happening here.

**Why am I getting that exception?**

Comment: My guess would be some interaction with classes that are being loaded implicitly; `PrintException` does extend `IOException`, and this *feels* like the inexplicable `HeadlessException`s when using something not obviously Swing-related. I suggest filing a bug about a possible hidden class dependency.

Comment: Are the classes/jars on the modulepath or the classpath? Are any modules defined for your code?

Comment: @MichaelEaster on the classpath - I haven't defined any module. It's a simple project with a pom.xml with a dependency on TestNG and jmockit and one file (the Test class in the question). The pom includes an argLine of `-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf` for surefire to allow jmockit to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [issue](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/428) has been fixed for JMockit 1.34.

During startup, JMockit modifies a JRE class (adding a few fields) in order to provide support for the mocking of JRE classes. The actual class which gets modified is arbitrary, and `javax.print.PrintException` was used (as a secondary choice) just because it usually never gets loaded in a typical test run. On JDK 9, this class is not accessible from the "base" module, so it was now replaced by another one which is.

Answer (score 8):

The IllegalAccessError hints that JMockit has instrumented ProcessBuilder (in java.base) with a reference to an exception in the java.desktop module. I don't know why it choose this exception, that may be something for the JMockit mailing list. However it does explain why `--add-reads` fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks - I've raised the issue there: https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/428